# Save Accented Characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We accept the accented characters such as `Ḿấxiḿứś` from a html form, when using hibernate saves it into the database the string becomes `??xi???`

Then I did a SQL update, trying to write the accented words directly into the database, the same result happened.

The desired behavior is to set into the dabase as what it is.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

I have tried to google it, someone said I need to change the database collation to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`. But I can't find this options from the dropdown.

Comment: What does your **table structure** look like? What columns do you have, what **datatypes** are they?? To support all accented characters, you most like need Unicode-capable `NVARCHAR` (not just `VARCHAR`)

Comment: @marc_s It was VARCHAR I just changed to NVARCHAR it still doesn't work, and my current database Collation is Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: in reality hibernate handles it automatically, all you need to do it to change the column type to NVARCHAR and make sure the database collation is accent sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN coloumn_name NVARCHAR(40) null
```

if you are using hibernate that's all you need.

I have attempted to change the table collation but it didn't work, maybe
you have to backup your data, create a fresh database with the new collation 
then pop back the data.

my database setting the collation is AS (accent sensitive), please make sure
yours has the same setting

Answer (score 7):

Only one of these works: nvarchar datatype and N prefix for unicode constants.

```
DECLARE 
    @foo1 varchar(10) = 'Ḿấxiḿứś', 
    @foo2 varchar(10) = N'Ḿấxiḿứś', 
    @fooN1 nvarchar(10) = 'Ḿấxiḿứś', 
    @fooN2 nvarchar(10) = N'Ḿấxiḿứś';

SELECT @foo1, @foo2, @fooN1, @fooN2;
```

You have to ensure that all datatypes are nvarchar end to end (columns, parameters, etc)

Collation is not the issue: this is for sorting and comparison for nvarchar

Comment: I am using hibernate not directly querying the database using sql

Comment: @shanyangqu: this is an example. But, you need to fix hibernate and the model.. like I said with "You have to ensure that all datatypes are nvarchar end to end"

Comment: I have done this, now all of them are Nvarchar, but still not working

Comment: @shanyangqu: in Hibernate too? And this won't fix existing data

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE "tablename"

Alter COLUMN "columnname" nvarchar(64) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```