# Accent Characters Causing issues

Tags: sql, ssis

How do I get rid of this the weird symbol is this name in a SQL table?  V**�**squez De Ulloa?  It is coming into a SQL Server database, stripping the accent character and replacing it with this. I am moving that data into a flat file and trying to upload. It is causing my ssis package to fail.

Comment: Pleaase post the create table statement.
Whichever column holds this value needs to be NVARCHAR.
Also check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586116/save-accented-characters-in-sql-server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [characters appearing incorrectly even with Unicode source and destination (SSIS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591298/characters-appearing-incorrectly-even-with-unicode-source-and-destination-ssis)